# issues with simple algebraic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$ab + a + b = 250$

$bc + b + c = 300$

$ac + a + c = 216$

then find $a + b + c = ?$

---

**MY APPROACH:**

(i) * c , (ii) * a , (iii) * b then we get

$abc + ac + bc = 250c$

$abc + ab + ac = 300a$

$abc + ab + bc = 216b$

(iv)+(v)+(vi)

$3abc + 2ac +2ab + 2bc = 300a + 216b +250c$

now i cant solve it ?? how to solve??

Comment: $$ (a+1)(b+1) = 251, \;  (b+1)(c+1)=301, \; (c+1)(a+1)= 217.  $$

Comment: how??? did not understand...please explain

Comment: You can certainly verify, by for example expanding $(a+1)(b+1)$, that the first result is correct.

Comment: Will added $1$ to both sides of each equation, then factored each left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{cases}
ab+a+b=250 \\
bc+b+c=300 \\
ac+a+c=216 \\
\end{cases}
it seems of no difficulty: a system of 3 equations and 3 variables...
Let's start by adding 1 to every equations, we obtain:
\begin{cases}
ab+a+b+1=(a+1)(b+1)=251 \\
bc+b+c+1=(c+1)(b+1)=301 \\
ac+a+c+1=(a+1)(c+1)=217 \\
\end{cases}
Now let's substitute $a+1 = x, b+1 =y, c+1 = z$, so we can reduce the amount of calculus needed, in fact to solve
\begin{cases}
xy=251 \\
yz=301 \\
xz=217 \\
\end{cases}
you only need to find $x$ (or $y$) in the first equation, substitute it in the last (or second) equation, and then do another substitution. Then subtract 1, and you'll find the solutions:

$(a,b,c) = (-1-\sqrt{\frac{7781}{43}}, -1-\sqrt{\frac{10793}{31}}, -1-7\sqrt{\frac{1333}{251}})$

and

$(a,b,c) = (\sqrt{\frac{7781}{43}}-1, \sqrt{\frac{10793}{31}}-1, 7\sqrt{\frac{1333}{251}}-1)$

Comment: Author is asking how to solve it, not what the solution is, so it seems this doesn't engage with the question.

Comment: oook, understood!