# How to solve these $3$ equations for three unknowns $x$,$y$,$z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

**Question:**

Solve:

$xy+x+y=23\tag{1}$

$yz+y+z=31\tag{2}$

$zx+z+x=47\tag{3}$

**My attempt:**

By adding all we get

$$\sum xy +2\sum x =101$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $z$, $(2)$ by $x$, and $(3)$  by $y$ and adding altogether gives

$$3xyz+ 2\sum xy =31x+47y+23z$$

Then, from above two equations after eliminating $\sum xy$ term we get

$$35x+51y+27z=202+3xyz$$

After that subtracting $(1)\times 3z$ from equation just above (to eliminate $3xyz$ term) gives

$$35x +51y-3z(14+x+y)=202\implies (x+y)[35-3z]+16y-42z=202$$

I tried pairwise subtraction of  $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ but it also seems to be not working.

Please give me some hint so that I can proceed or provide with the answer.

Comment: What are the constraints on x, y, and z?

Comment: Duplicate of [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669228/solve-system-of-simulataneous-equations-in-3-variables), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991748/system-of-equations-contest-problem), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695496/issues-with-simple-algebraic-equations), but for the numbers on the RHS.

Comment: @Dancrumb I don't think so, given that solving this with general system solving techniques is a tad bit overkill.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hint: Put
$$X=x+1$$
$$Y=y+1$$
$$Z=z+1$$

Then we have

$$XY=24$$
$$YZ=32$$
$$ZX=48$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: K  : that was nice trick ......now i can take it

Answer (score 15):

We can use [Simon's favorite factoring trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick).

$$xy+x+y+1=(x+1)(y+1)$$

This tells us

$$(x+1)(y+1)=24$$$$(y+1)(z+1)=32$$$$(x+1)(z+1)=48$$So, we know that $x+1 = \pm\frac{\sqrt{24\cdot32\cdot48}}{32}\to x=5,-7$. Likewise, you can find the other variables.

Comment: amazing thank you ...i will take it from here .....

Comment: You could also have $x+1 = -\frac{\sqrt{24 \cdot 32 \cdot 48}}{32} \rightarrow x = -7$.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the first equation into an equation that expresses y in terms of x.

You can convert the third equation into an equation that expresses z in terms of x.

You can substitute these formulas for y and z into the second equation.  **This gives a single equation, in a single variable** (x).

The single equation can be simplified, by letting v = x + 1, and substituting v-1 in for x.  Then you can multiply through by v².  Notice that you are assuming that v ≠ 0. Then you can solve for v.  Since this is a second order equation, you will get two solutions (which might be equal to each other).

Now you can **solve for x**.  (It is v-1).  Notice that you are assuming that x ≠ -1.

Now you can solve the first equation for y, and the third equation for z.

Now you need to **make sure you don't have a divide-by-zero error**.  In other words, check what values you get for y and z if x were equal to -1.  Since these are the asymptotes of the hyperbolas that are hinted at by marshal craft's answer, y and z turn out to be ±∞.  This demonstrates that it was okay to assume that x ≠ -1.

Now you can perform your **check-by-substitution**, to verify that both solutions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$(2)-(1)$ gives

$$(z-x)(y+1)=8=(z+1-(x+1))(y+1)$$

$(3)-(2)$ becomes

$$(x-y)(z+1)=16=(x+1-(y+1))(z+1)$$

$(3)-(1)$ yields to

$$(z-y)(x+1)=24=(z+1-(y+1))(x+1)$$

From here, we put
$$X=x+1,\;Y=y+1,\; Z=z+1$$
thus

$$YZ-YX=8$$
$$ZX-ZY=16$$
$$XZ-XY=24$$

Comment: OP mentioned he took pairwise differences and couldn't make progress.

Answer (score -1):

Consider first equation :

XY + X + Y = 23
=> X ( Y + 1 ) = 23 -Y
=> X = (23-Y)/(Y+1) -(a)

Consider second equation :

YZ + Y +Z = 31
=> Y (Z+1)=31-Z
=>Y=(31-Z)/(Z+1)-(b)

Consider third equation :

XZ +Z+X = 47
=> Z(X+1)=47-X
=>Z=(47-X)/(X+1)-(c)

Now put the value of z from eq c into eq b , then simply that equation , then put the simplified value of Y from eq b into eq A , then from there you will get the value of X , then put that value into eq c you will get the value of Z and finally put the value of Z into eq b to get the value of Y .